# adding taxes to a checkout api transaction

Tags: square-connect, square

I'm having trouble adding taxes to a square checkout api transaction.  Everything else is working, but I can't make the taxes part work.  It would be appreciated if someone could post a few lines of the relevant php code that adds taxes at the item or order level.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a PHP Checkout request that create a $5.00 charge, with a 10% tax (50 cent) at the order level:

```
  $checkout_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\CheckoutApi();
  $request_body = new \SquareConnect\Model\CreateCheckoutRequest(
    [
      "idempotency_key" => uniqid(),
      "order" => [
        "line_items" => [
        [
          "name" => "Test Payment",
          "quantity" => "1",
          "base_price_money" => [
            "amount" => 500,
            "currency" => "USD"
          ]
        ]],
        "taxes" => [
          [
            "name" => "This is so taxing",
            "type" => "ADDITIVE",
            "percentage" => "10"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  );
  $response = $checkout_api->createCheckout($location_id, $request_body);
```

If you want to add it at the item level, you would just move the `taxes` array to inside the `line_items` object. Example of 2 items, one with tax and one without:

```
  $checkout_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\CheckoutApi();
  $request_body = new \SquareConnect\Model\CreateCheckoutRequest(
    [
      "idempotency_key" => uniqid(),
      "order" => [
        "line_items" => [
        [
          "name" => "Test Payment",
          "quantity" => "1",
          "base_price_money" => [
            "amount" => 500,
            "currency" => "USD"
          ],
          "taxes" => [
            [
              "name" => "This is so taxing",
              "type" => "ADDITIVE",
              "percentage" => "10"
            ]
          ]
        ],
        [
          "name" => "Test Payment Without Tax",
          "quantity" => "1",
          "base_price_money" => [
            "amount" => 500,
            "currency" => "USD"
          ]
        ]],
      ]
    ]
  );
  $response = $checkout_api->createCheckout($location_id, $request_body);
```